# Apache Cordova - Hello World - Grey triangle in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

What is this *grey triangle* that appear when I launch the basic Hello World Cordova app in the emulator ? The emulator is a Nexus 4 on API 23. I tried a Nexus 5X API 23, the same triangle shows up.

[image]

This triangle does not show up when I run `cordova run browser`.

Comment: Have you tried to examine the triangle with dev tools or an inspector?

Comment: @Phonolog : Nothing appears in the inspector and there is no dom elements that could lead to this triangle. Seems to me that it's a glitch in the emulator's graphic renderer.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely graphic glitch when I use the host computer graphics card for rendering, ie 'Hardware Graphic Rendering' for the AVD.

In the AVD Configuration, when I set 'Emulated Performance' to 'Software - GLES 2.0' the triangle does not show up.

[image]

I will stay in hardware graphic rendering, as the software one is very slow, and just ignore the glitch for now.

It's probably linked to some native Android animation when the app is launched or when the device to turn to landscape/portrait : when I turn the AVD, the triangle glitch is always in the bottom-right corner, and almost always pointing to the bottom of the device.

If someone is interested in my specific configuration that causes this issue, it's a Dell Latitude E6410 on Win7, fresh install of Cordova 6.1.1, Android platform 5.1.1, Android Studio 2.1.1.